# TCPClient works Locally but not externally System.IO error

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a client and a server and it works locally on my computer. Although when I deploy it all clients are rejected with the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at SlientServer_v2_1.ConnectionHandle.SendRequestInformation(Client target, Int32 messageId) in c:\Users\Ya\Dropbox\Private\Visual Studio\Projects\SlientServer_v2_1\SlientServer_v2_1\ConnectionHandle.cs:line 136
```

Here is my code for sending data:

```
 public static void SendRequestInformation(Client target, int messageId)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = target.getClientSocket().GetStream();
        byte[] byteData = null;
        switch (messageId)
        {
            case 0:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ping");
                break;
            case 1:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hand");
                break;
            case 3:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("osif");
                break;
            case 4:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("idle");
                break;
            case 5:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("cpus");
                break;
            case 6:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mine");
                break;
            case 2:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rein");
                break;
            case 7:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bcac");
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            byte[] bufferedToSend = new byte[byteData.Length + 4];
            byte[] lengthOfSend = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteData.Length);
            Array.Copy(lengthOfSend, bufferedToSend, 4);
            byteData.CopyTo(bufferedToSend, 4);
       --- This is 136  ----   stream.Write(bufferedToSend, 0, bufferedToSend.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            ClientHandle.RemoveFromClientPool(target, "Unable to reach Client");
        }
    }
```

I've looked at the following for clues, no dice [An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862817/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

The first message send is probably case 1.

Comment: Firewall, perhaps? Can you try disabling it in the remote system?

Comment: Are you asking me to disable firewall on my client?

Comment: @RicardoPeres Disable all known firewalls on server no idea still same problem.

Comment: Yes, I meant on the server... well, it's something else, then...